# Column data in dataframe is coming as individual list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a lottery game here in Brazil that at the end of the year (12/31/2022) pays a higher amount, I did the webscrap and captured all the games and included them in the dataframe.

[image]

Now I want to get only the games from the 12/31st of each year that had these games to use them as a test in a neural network prediction, but when including in a new dataframe with only these games, each data in the column is as a list as shown below.

[image]

I'm still learning Pandas and the code below that I used seems a little complicated, it must be simpler, because I still don't know all the properties of pandas.

```
df_mega_virada = pd.DataFrame(columns=['concurso','data', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6'])

datas = ['31/12/2009','31/12/2010','31/12/2011','31/12/2012','31/12/2013','31/12/2014',
         '31/12/2015','31/12/2016','31/12/2017','31/12/2018','31/12/2019','31/12/2020']

for x, y in enumerate(datas):
   df_mega_virada.loc[x] = df3.query(f"data == '{y}'").concurso.values,df3.query(f"data == '{y}'").data.values,df3.query(f"data == '{y}'").b1.values, df3.query(f"data == '{y}'").b2.values,df3.query(f"data == '{y}'").b3.values,df3.query(f"data == '{y}'").b4.values,df3.query(f"data == '{y}'").b5.values,df3.query(f"data == '{y}'").b6.values
```

What I hope:

[image]

The link to .csv file:
[File csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rG7lxwno7NDIX_pXTtncBz023LNH5O0F/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: How about you share all the sample data with me and I promise to split the money if I win! I am joking! But seriously, I think this will help you assuming the dates are all in the `data` column in the `df3` dataframe: `df3.loc[(df3['data'].dt.month == 12) & (df3['data'].dt.day == 31)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the following logic to perform the filter you are looking for:

1. Create a separate series of the month and a separate series for the day of month.
2. Filter rows by month == 12 and day == 31 in the dataframe.

```py
    month_series = df3["data"].dt.month

    day_of_month_series = df3["data"].dt.day

    df3_clean = df3[
      (month_series == 12) &
      (day_of_month_series == 31)
    ]
```

Comment: Ben, Got it, simple solution and me trying something "wacky". Thank you very much.